# How to remove numerous modules from android platform build?

Tags: android, android-source

Our chipset vendor gives a drop of the Android platform with hundreds of useless modules. Some are included using `LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional debug` but I don't want this module to show up in any build at all. Some are included by doing `PRODUCT_PACKAGES += junk-app`. I could go through all the Android.mk files one at a time cleaning this stuff up but that is tiresome and problematic for merging if the vendor gives us a new drop.

I can use `LOCAL_OVERRIDES_PACKAGES` to get rid of the `PRODUCT_PACKAGES` but that doesn't work on shared libraries saved to `/system/vendor/bin` or prebuilt files that are copied in `/system/etc/`.

The ones with `LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS` set to values that include `eng` or `debug` are the most annoying.

Comment: If your android phone includes `audioflacapp` you know who I'm talking about. Doesn't every android phone need a commandline only tool to encode FLAC audio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there doesn't seem to be any silver bullet, here was my strategy:

- Remove the `debug` and `eng` tags from the `LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS` in a bunch of makefiles (tedious but no other obvious choice)
- Use `ifneq ($(TARGET_VENDOR), mycompany)` to get rid of things added to `PRODUCT_PACKAGES`